# jQuery UI - Autocomplete friends lists from facebook Graph API using JSONP

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I need to grab a JSON array from Facebook's Graph API.
I am using the facebook JS-SDK inside a jquery function.

Basically this function gets an access token from the active user, then adds it to the callback to get the list of friends from the Graph API.
I need the UI autocomplete function to  show a list of friends in a drop down below the input item.

I can call the graph API correctly, but I can't target the JSON array properly within the autocomplete function.

JS ->

```
$(function() {

    //Facebook Connection
    FB.init({
        //Put app ID here
        appId: 'MYAPPID', 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true, 
        status: true });

    //Function to output API call to console
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
    }

    //Check if logged in to FB
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {

            //Get Access Token
            var accessToken = response.session.access_token;
            //Get Callback URL for API call
            var tokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + accessToken + "&callback=?";

            //Output callback URL to 'div#access'
            $('#access').append('<p>' + tokenUrl + '</p>');

            $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    //Make call to Graph API
                    $.ajax({
                        //Use tokenUrl for callback URL
                        url: tokenUrl,
                        //Use JSONP for external JSON callback
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: function () { return $("#name").val() }
                        },
                        //Output request data to console
                        success: function(results){
                            console.log(results);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });

        } else {
            // Show Login....
        }
    });
});
```

HTML ->

```
<div id="access"></div>
<input id="name" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

The js console is giving me these results ->

```
Object
data: Array[304]
__proto__: Object
```

So the ui autocomplete function is getting called properly, but the input item isn't filling out with results, as it is getting the entire array wrapped in the 'data' wrapper.

I think I need to target the wrapper inside the json array for my results, but I don't know how to go about doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you get a chance, you could mark this answered. I would appreciate it.

Comment: is there any way to take the "id" from the data of the chosen name and pass it to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function needs to change:

```
$( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    //Make call to Graph API
                    $.ajax({
                        //Use tokenUrl for callback URL
                        url: tokenUrl,
                        //Use JSONP for external JSON callback
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: function () { return $("#name").val() }
                        },
                        //Output request data to console
                        success: function(results){
                            console.log(results);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

to this:

```
    $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, add) {
                    //Make call to Graph API
                    $.ajax({
                        //Use tokenUrl for callback URL
                        url: tokenUrl,
                        //Use JSONP for external JSON callback
                        dataType: "jsonp",

                        //Output request data to console
                        success: function(results){
                            add(results.data); // //pass array to callback 
                        }
                    });
                },
```

the `add` parameter will send the results back to the autocomplete.

EDIT: Since results.data return an array of objects, each object must have either value or label or both properties.

FOr example,

```
var valid = results.data[0].label || results.data[0].value;
if (valid) {
   console.log('this is ok');
   add(results.data);
} else {
    // You need to format the result
    var formatted = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< results.data.length; i++) {
        // filter results   
        if (results.data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf($('#name').val()) > 0)
            formatted.push(results.data[i].whatever_field_is_the_label)
    }
    add(formatted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Hmm, nearly there... This adds a <ul> below the input and it is filled with <li>'s, but they are all empty. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `console.log(results.data[0]);` give you?

Comment: That just returns the first item in the array, regardless of what I type in the input...

Comment: I know, but is that a string? or an object?

Comment: This gives me an error -> Uncaught ReferenceError: results is not defined. 
I'm using  formatted.push(results.data[i].name)

Comment: @reekogi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2374/discussion-between-joey-and-reekogi)